# How do I test that a string is a sentence?

Tags: text, natural-language

For example, consider

```
string = "this is a sentence."
```

The best way I can think about is `DictionaryWordQ`. However, `"this  a is sentence."` can't be found in this way. `"is sentence this  a."`  `"is sentence a this."`ares not sentences. because they are not grammatically  correct.

I'm doing a cryptography analysis for some text messages. I want to write code to tell some combinations whether it's true or not.

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: `TextStructure` might be helpful here.  It doesn't not tell you what's wrong with the second example, but can be used to show that one has a verb and one does not.

Comment: @bobthechemist I just want to test the string is True or False about a sentence.

Comment: I think both examples are sentences -- voting to close as opinion based. (But I like the answer of @bobthechemist .)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Well, there are lots of machine learning methods these days which handle fuzzy problems like this just fine. Defining what is or isn't a sentence is going to be impossible. But writing a problem that classifies strings reasonably, and usually returns `True` for obviously correct sentences and `False` for obvious gibberish is doable. What it would or could do in the middle (non-obvious cases) and whether it could be useful for any real application are different questions.

Comment: I guess this is more or less the job of engineers at https://www.grammarly.com :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs "Defining what is or isn't a sentence is going to be impossible." -- thanks for mentioning this. I am/was expecting one of the outcomes of my close vote to be a definition of what is a sentence. (It can be a narrower, OP-specific one.) (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For example, I would say that "this, a sentence." is a valid sentence, but using `TextStructure` -- as shown by @bobthechemist -- gives `False` for that sentence. So, a narrowing definition is needed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, a sentence *in English* contains a subject, predicate and complete thought.  @AntonAntonov's example isn't a sentence using this definition because it contains no predicate.  Additionally, it seems that *grammatical correctness* is not a requirement for a sentence, as even with grammatical errors, one can still have the three aforementioned components: "I is hungry."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Mathematica* has the experimental (as of v12) function `TextStructure` which provides some guidance with this question, but things get tricky.

```
s1 = "This is a sentence.";
s2 = "This a is sentence.";
s3 = "This a sentence.";
sentenceQ[s_String]:=StringContainsQ[
    TextStructure[s,"ConstituentStrings"],"Sentence"];
```

`sentenceQ` yields True for `s1` and `s2` and False for the last example.  Not having a verb phrase is grounds for `TextStructure` to not declare that the string is a sentence.

Clearly, `s2` is grammatically incorrect.  Less clear, is whether or not a grammatically incorrect phrase is still considered a sentence.

If we take one definition of a sentence as containing a subject and a predicate, then `s2` is a sentence with a subject **This a**  and a predicate **is sentence**.  Granted, the subject and predicate are nonsensical.  *Should Mathematica know that?*  At this point, I think the question belongs [at a different StackExchange website](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

I decided to stop my search for grammatical truth once I learned that Mathematica and Yoda agree:

[image]

I do not believe that current built-in functions of Mathematica provide the tools necessary to address the OPs problem, which I interpret to be *identifying grammar errors in a sentence.*  The reason can be summarized by comparing the output of `TextStructure` on "The baseball team are established." and "The baseball team is established."  Both yield the same parts of speech, notably, "is" and "are" are both labeled correctly as verbs.  However, in order for grammar checking to pick up this error, the two verbs must be tagged differently.  [A thesis has been written](http://www.danielnaber.de/languagetool/download/style_and_grammar_checker.pdf)  on creating an open-source grammar checker which describes parts-of-speech tagging in more detail.  Perhaps if this level of detail is incorporated into future versions of the linguistics functions in Mathematica, this problem will become more tractable.

Comment: But OP asked about "this a is sentence", for which this returns `True`. Perhaps this "a" is a sentence but that "a" is not a sentence. Would make more sense if we used `a1` and `a2` instead of `s1` and `s2`. This illustrates why this is going to be difficult to do reliably :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I noticed that after posting and instead of updating my answer have been jumping down the rabbit hole of web-searching: "what is a sentence?".

Comment: Of course that was not a real criticism, and I already upvoted :-)

Comment: Your code is not working.
StringContainsQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringContainsQ[TextSTructure[This a is sentence.,ConstituentStrings],Sentence].